# Zoom size and location keeps changing when I switch monitors. Is there anything I can do, or a way to get back to it quickly?

Tags: macos, ventura, accessibility, zoom

Especially after plugging in to a TV, when I go back to laptop mode, the zoom window is tiny. I would love to know a way to stop it from changing, or if there is a quicker way to get to the size and location function (currently it's system settings -> accessibility -> zoom -> size and location button).

I'm on a 2019 MBP Intel 16" running Ventura.

Thanks!